# Eclipse shortcut CTRL+M behavior

Tags: eclipse, editor, settings, default, maximize

In eclipse we have the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> shortcut for maximizing windows.

But when you have two editors opened side by side, it maximizes both editors.

Is there anyway to change the default behavior of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> so it only maximizes one window?

(Personally this is the behavior i need 9 out of 10 times using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can enable this by changing your presentation preference. normally maximizing single editors is not possible (since 3.2 the [maximize](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-39g.htm) action is only available for views and the complete editor area, you can't maximize a single editor)

but how to change the presentation then?

click Window -> Preferences

in the preferences goto General -> Appearance, and the change the 'current presentation' to 'Eclipse 2.1 Style Presentation' or 'Classic' and restart eclipse. now you can maximize the editors on their own.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have changed the layout to Classic, and the ctrl+m key is working as normal!

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to change my eclipse' appearance into classic since I used to be with Dark.

So what I do is change the shortcut keys on "Preferences > General > Keys". You can define whatever you want from here.